# Resque not running workers to pick jobs from queue - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I have a resque job to run. I tried queuing my job to a queue by issuing command:
`Resque.enqueue("QUEUE", params)`

It pushes the job to the queue. I tried running resque interface as localhost:3000/resque. It showed me pending jobs to be taken.. But it also shows that there are no worker running. I ran rake task to start the worker by command: (`QUEUE='*' bundle exec rake resque:work`).
My redis instance  is Resque.redis = `#<Redis::Namespace:0x007f82183d0120 @namespace=:resque, @redis=#<Redis client v2.2.2 connected to redis://localhost:6379/0 (Redis v0.07)>>`.

I dont get any error as well when i try to run that rake task.. Please let me know if you need further information..

Comment: which version of resque and also and try calling this Resque.enqueue([Some Class], params) something like `Resque.enqueue(Archive, self.id, branch)` where Archive over here is worker class

Comment: Resque verison is v1.20.0. I will try that and see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is old but hopefully, this might help whoever stumbles here.

If you use `resque-lock` or `resque-queue-lock`, your queue might be locked, and it might not be released because the process could've been killed before releasing the lock.

In our case, we find all the locks

```
Resque::Plugins::Queue::Lock.all_queue_locks
```

And find the one we need to remove and just delete the key from redis

```
Resque.redis.del(the_key_name)
```

`the_key_name` above is the exact string you find the previous step.